# Android get Google Play Store app version

Tags: android, google-play, version

I am using this code to get the Google Play Store app version but this is causing my app to hang. Please specify another way to get the app version or how I can use this code to make the app not hang and run successfully.

```java
public class VersionChecker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String newVersion;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "trai.gov.in.dnd" + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
                    .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                    .first()
                    .ownText();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newVersion;
    }
}
```

This is my code to get the app version from asynctask

```
VersionChecker versionChecker = new VersionChecker();
try {
    String appVersionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
    String mLatestVersionName = versionChecker.execute().get();
    if (versionChecker.compareVersionNames(appVersionName, mLatestVersionName) == -1) {
        showAppUpdateDialog();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: its for an specific app ?

Comment: Yes for an specific app

Comment: Could you paste the code of the function which is calling this async task ?

Comment: how did you fix the compareVersionNames error?

Comment: Hello bro, are you still using asyntask until this day or did you already find an alternative on this since asyntask was already deprecated.

Comment: As of May 26th, 2022, Google has changed their Play Store page and have hidden the latest "Version" behind a clickable button that displays a modal. Instead of just parsing/scraping the page, we had to use a headless browser to click that button, display the modal and then parse the modal for the Version. What a PITA. If someone knows a better method, please share!

Comment: @JoshuaPinter if you have found any new or working methods could you please share them?
if not, could you please share the method you mentioned?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanHasanato We ended up doing it on our back-end and our mobile app just pings our API to retrieve the latest version number instead. Was much easier to maintain that way.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Hmm, I'm actually using Firebase to store the newest version and compare it with the current version in the app ‍♂️

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace your code

```java
.get()
.select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
.first()
.ownText();
```

with below:

```java
.get()
.select(".hAyfc .htlgb")
.get(3)
.ownText();
```

it will work..!

Comment: You need to use .get(5) now instead of .get(3), but this is the only thing I have found that works.

Comment: how did you fix the compareVersionNames error?

Answer (score 2):

The problem arises because the element `div [itemprop = softwareVersion]` is no longer found on the Google Play website (therefore it no longer returns the version number), it should only be changed to a new query with the changes made by google on your website.

Note: Take into account that if the structure is changed again, this code must be changed.

I hope it helps

Update: 12/09/2019

```
public class VersionChecker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        private String newVersion;

        try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "com.example.package" + "&hl=en")
                .timeout(30000)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                .get();
        if (document != null) {
            Elements element = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version");
            for (Element ele : element) {
                if (ele.siblingElements() != null) {
                    Elements sibElemets = ele.siblingElements();
                    for (Element sibElemet : sibElemets) {
                        newVersion = sibElemet.text();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return newVersion;
    }
}
```

**Codigo Java**

```
VersionChecker versionChecker = new VersionChecker();
try {
    String latestVersion = versionChecker.execute().get();
    String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME.replace("-DEBUG","");
    if (latestVersion != null && !latestVersion.isEmpty()) {
        if (!latestVersion.equals(versionName)) {
            showDialogToSendToPlayStore();
        }else{
            continueWithTheLogin();
        }
    }
    Log.d("update", "Current version " + Float.valueOf(versionName) + ", Playstore version " + Float.valueOf(latestVersion));

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Nice ! Your solution is better than the top one.

Comment: What is showDialogToSendToPlayStore()? Should I add a library?

Answer (score 2):

1. It seems you use the "app-version" shown on the Google Play Store website to trigger an "update popup" to your users and notify when a new version is available. First of all, Google Play Store website is changing often, so that's not very reliable as your app might not be able to "parse/handle" those changes. If you want to keep that approach, some other answers already explained how to parse the right HTML tag and how to do in the background correctly. Keep in mind your app will be still responsible for the "parsing", eventually you would do the parsing remotely on a web-server, and expose to your app a stable API endpoint to retrieve the "latest-version" of your own app. If you do not want to bother with parsing HTML tags or host your own API, there are third-party APIs that can do that for you. We provide one such API here: https://42matters.com/docs/app-market-data/android/apps/lookup (it returns a JSON object with the latest "version name" of the app).
2. You could also use https://github.com/danielemaddaluno/Android-Update-Checker to not implement your own code, under the hood it does more or less the same as you do.
3. Personally I would use a remote service like Firebase Remote Config https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config or a simple JSON file hosted on your website specifying the latest published version of your app (just remember to change it once the update of your app is really published on Google Play, nowadays it might take a while). Also, I would rather use the "versionCode" as explained here: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
   With this approach you could "trigger" the update when you want, more control on your side (especially in case you want to revert the "Please update" message, useful if you find a bug in the latest version you published)

Answer (score 0):

Change this two lines

```
{
 newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "package name" + "&hl=en")
     .timeout(30000)
     .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
....
```

you are using  `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` but you need `package_name`

`BuildConfig` is provided by Gradle. If you are not building using `Gradle` then you cannot access the package name using `BuildConfig`.

I would use `Context.getPackageName()` because the result is provided from the operating system, rather than a constant in build parameters.

Comment: Okay let me do and check.

Comment: you are doing this inside an asynctask ?

Comment: It is still talking time for app to load.

Comment: Yes inside an async task

Comment: do you have internet permisions in your manifest ? can you post your error log ? thanks

Comment: I have internet permissions in manifest and there is no error. Its just that app takes time to load the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it into AysncTask

```
 //********* Check for Updated Version of APP
    private class GetVersionCode extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
        String currentVersion = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

            String newVersion = null;

            try {
                currentVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
                newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + Activity.this.getPackageName() + "&hl=it")
                        .timeout(30000)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                        .get()
                        .select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]")
                        .first()
                        .ownText();
                return newVersion;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String onlineVersion) {
            super.onPostExecute(onlineVersion);
            if (onlineVersion != null && !onlineVersion.isEmpty()) {
                if (!currentVersion.equalsIgnoreCase(onlineVersion)) {
                    //Todo code here

                }
            }
            Log.d("update", "Current version " + currentVersion + "playstore version " + onlineVersion);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, OP says that he have an asynctask already, check the comments in my asnwer

Comment: Ohh I see... Probably it will clear it if he is doing anything wrong in that.

Comment: No problem dude :)

Answer (score 0):

Google change the API from 'softwareVersion' to 'currentVersion' and we can get the same version using ".hAyfc .htlgb"

Below code will not work i.e.

```java
latestVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + context.getPackageName() + "&hl=en").timeout(30000) .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6") .referrer("http://www.google.com") .get().select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]").first().ownText();
```

Instead of above code just add this code, it will work fine i.e.

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + context.getPackageName() + "&hl=en").timeout(30000)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6").referrer("http://www.google.com").get();
    if(document != null) {
        if(document.select(".hAyfc .htlgb").get(5) != null) {
            latestVersion = document.select(".hAyfc .htlgb").get(5).ownText();
        } else {
            latestVersion = currentVersion;
        }
    }

// Note: There is no official API to get the current application version from Google Play. So use the above code to get the current version. Sometimes get(5).ownText() will change as google is updating the Google Play site. [Previously it was working with get(2).ownText()].
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this,

Replace the code ,

```
                .get()
                .select("div:containsOwn(Current Version)")
                .next()
                .text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this much easier using UpdateManager - https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/update/UpdateManager

You can setup your Update Manager as such

```
// Creates instance of the manager.
AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(this);

// Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

//On Success Listener
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(this);
```

In your On Success method, you can call

```
result.availableVersionCode()
```

Which returns 0 when the version is not different. Which if it is different you can just pull this value from your app directly.